# Hola tengo este error al descargar o instalar extenciones en vscode ,Error while fetching extensions. XHR failed

Tags: javascript, json, vscode, terminal, proxy

tengo este error en visual studio code, Error while fetching extensions. XHR failed, ya intente agregar las extencioes de forma manual y cuando lo hago me deriba al archivo setting.json no me atrevo a moverle ahi, ayuda porfavor y gracias.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.